# How to plot boudaries around clusters in fuzzy c-means (python)

Tags: python, plot, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning, fuzzy-c-means

I am using unsupervised fuzzy c-means for clustering with 3 clusters. From the clustering I obtain a matrix with coordinates of centroids and a matrix with the membership of each point in the three different clusters. I want to plot a decision boundary that delimits each cluster but I have found only examples for supervised classification. Any help?